# Prove that If $ae^{i\theta} + b e^{3i\theta} = c,$ where $a, b, c$ are real number, either $a \pm b = \pm c$ or $b(b - a) = c^2.$

Tags: complex-numbers

If $ae^{i\theta} + b e^{3i\theta} = c,$ where $a, b, c$ are real number, then prove that either $a \pm b = \pm c$ or $b(b - a) = c^2.$

What I have done, just express $e^{i\theta}$ as $\cos\theta + i \sin\theta,$ similarly for $e^{3i \theta},$ put this in the equation given above. Then equating real part and imaginary part, I got $4b\cos^3\theta + (a - 3b)\cos\theta -c = 0.$ From this point can I get the result?

Comment: is there a condition on $\theta$ ?

Comment: @DeepSea I dont think it is needed. Check my answer!

Comment: no there is no condition given on $\theta.$

Answer (score 4):

Let us assume that $a\neq0$.

Let $z_1,z_2,z_3$ be the roots of the third degree equation:

$$az^3+bz-c=0 \tag{1}$$

with $z_1:=e^{i\theta}$ (by hypothesis).

As (1) has real coefficients, by conjugation, $z_2:=e^{-i\theta}$ is as well a root.

Using Vieta's formulas, we have

$$\begin{cases}z_1+z_2+z_3=0 & (i)\\z_1z_2+z_2z_3+z_3z_1=\frac{b}{a} & (ii) \\z_1z_2z_3=\frac{c}{a} & (iii) \end{cases}$$

(i) gives $z_3=-2 \cos(\theta)$.

Plugging this value of $z_3$ into (ii) gives $1-4\cos(\theta)^2=\frac{b}{a} $.

Do the same operation on (iii).

You are now close to the conclusion...

Remark: If $a=0$, using a direct reasoning, $be^{3i\theta}=c$ with real numbers $b$ and $c$ is only possible if $b=\pm c$ and $\theta=k \pi/3$.

Comment: Nice way to handle the problem

Comment: This is such a clean solution. Never would have thought of this. +1

Comment: Thanks. I have added the distinction between cases $a \neq 0$ and $a=0$.

Answer (score 3):

> $$a\sin\theta +b\sin3\theta=0\\\implies (a+3b)\sin\theta=4\sin^3\theta\\\implies \theta=2n\pi\ or\ (2n+1)\pi\ or\ \cos^2\theta={b-a\over 4b}$$

Now

> $$a\cos\theta+b\cos3\theta=c\\\implies\cos\theta\left(a+b(4\cos^2\theta-3)\right)=c$$

IF $\theta=2n\pi$

> $a+b=c$

ElseIF $\theta=(2n+1)\pi$

> $a+b=-c$

Else

> $$\cos\theta\left(a+b\left({b-a\over b}-3\right)\right)=c\\\implies \cos\theta=-{c\over 2b}\\\implies \cos^2\theta={c^2\over 4b^2}={b-a\over 4b}$$

BINGO!

Comment: Nice answer and job well done !

Comment: @DeepSea #HappyTohelp